# How do you flatten a 3d numpy array into a 2-d array of tuples?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have the following numpy array:

```
array([[[1, 1], [0, 5]],
       [[1, 2], [1, 6]],
       [[0, 3], [0, 7]]]
)
```

Of shape `(3,2,2)`

I'd like to reshape it into a 3x2 array of tuples. Ie.

```
array([[(1, 1), (0, 5)],
       [(1, 2), (1, 6)],
       [(0, 3), (0, 7)]]
)
```

Is there any way to do this in numpy without a python loop? My actual numpy array is very large.

Comment: Why?  Calculation performance will suffer.  Anyways, you need to make  a (3,2) object dtype array, and assign these values.  You'll need a list comprehension to convert the inner lists/dimension to tuples.

Comment: I need it as a fast way to create a 2d data structure of tuples

Comment: Need to cast it into a pandas dataframe, hence the need for it to be 2d

Answer (score 0):

```
In [48]: arr = np.array([[[1, 1], [0, 5]],
    ...:        [[1, 2], [1, 6]],
    ...:        [[0, 3], [0, 7]]]
    ...: )

In [49]: arr
Out[49]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [0, 5]],

       [[1, 2],
        [1, 6]],

       [[0, 3],
        [0, 7]]])

In [50]: import pandas as pd

In [51]: pd.DataFrame(arr)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(3, 2, 2)
```

Make a 2d object dtype array - start with a "blank":

```
In [52]: res = np.empty((3,2),object)

In [53]: res[:] = arr
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [53], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 res[:] = arr

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,2,2) into shape (3,2)
```

But if we first make a pure python list:

```
In [54]: res[:] = arr.tolist()

In [55]: res
Out[55]: 
array([[list([1, 1]), list([0, 5])],
       [list([1, 2]), list([1, 6])],
       [list([0, 3]), list([0, 7])]], dtype=object)

In [56]: pd.DataFrame(res)
Out[56]: 
        0       1
0  [1, 1]  [0, 5]
1  [1, 2]  [1, 6]
2  [0, 3]  [0, 7]
```

To make those object elements tuples, we need  a list comprehension.  This will be easiest if `res` starts as 1dL

```
In [64]: res = np.empty((6),object)

In [65]: [tuple(x) for x in arr.reshape(-1,2).tolist()]
Out[65]: [(1, 1), (0, 5), (1, 2), (1, 6), (0, 3), (0, 7)]

In [66]: res[:] = [tuple(x) for x in arr.reshape(-1,2).tolist()]

In [67]: res
Out[67]: array([(1, 1), (0, 5), (1, 2), (1, 6), (0, 3), (0, 7)], dtype=object)

In [68]: res.reshape(3,2)
Out[68]: 
array([[(1, 1), (0, 5)],
       [(1, 2), (1, 6)],
   [(0, 3), (0, 7)]], dtype=object)
```

Another approach is to make a structured array, whose 'tolist' produces tuples:

```
In [80]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf

In [81]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(arr, dtype=np.dtype('i,i'))
Out[81]: 
array([[(1, 1), (0, 5)],
       [(1, 2), (1, 6)],
       [(0, 3), (0, 7)]], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])

In [82]: pd.DataFrame(_.tolist())
Out[82]: 
        0       1
0  (1, 1)  (0, 5)
1  (1, 2)  (1, 6)
2  (0, 3)  (0, 7)
```

It's shorter but I don't know about speed.